# Get object in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a list of array. Avery array has an object, and I want to get the value of this object

My code as follow:

```
var data =[]

var children= response.data.children

children.forEach(function (child) {
    if(equipes.hasOwnProperty(child['id'])) {
        total += equipes[child['id']];
        dataequipes.push({
            id: child['id'],
            total: equipes[child['id']]
        });
    }
});

series.domain = domainId;
series.total = total;
series.details = dataequipes;
data.push(series);

return data;
```

In my other function I call the returned value and the result as follows:

[image: test]

But when I want to call the total value of object, I got always error:
I used data.total, `data['total']`... but without any result

Comment: _What error do you get?_

Comment: I get undefined

Comment: you never initialized `total`

Comment: undefined is not an error.

Comment: also, `total` is part of `series`, not of `data`. So it would be data[0]["total"] at best

Comment: the problem that a __proto__ javascript is added to array, so I have two objects, and I want to get just the first object, and I can't do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this;

```
let total = 0;
data.forEach(function (item) {
    if(item.hasOwnProperty('total')) {
        total = item.total 
    }
});
```

Comment: Another problems: you see that variable total is set to zero: so if a do total=total+item.total , the total is incremented, but when I do console.log(total) outside the boucle I get 0.  I'm working with angularjs but really I can't understand why the variable total is zero. normally should be modified to his final value.

Comment: Probably a problem with scope. If I don't see your code I cannot help you.